# SQL SELECT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Employee logs table

```
Employeeno        | day_in      | day_out
0123              | 2017-06-20  | 2017-06-21
0123              | 2017-06-21  | 2017-06-22
0122              | 2017-06-20  | 2017-06-21
0122              | 2017-06-22  | 2017-06-23
0121              | 2017-06-23  | 2017-06-24
```

I wanted to query employees who has day_in(datetime) less than 2017-06-21 and day in greater than 2017-06-21 which is employee number 0122.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where is your Problem?

Comment: If it is a single table, you will not need to JOIN like your question states.

Comment: `day_in less than 2017-06-21 ... and day_in greater than 2017-06-21` -
 There is no way that your stated condition will ever produce any results.

Comment: i think he means day_in less than 2017-06-21 and day_out great than 2017-06-21

Comment: Even that would produce nothing with the data as given.

Comment: But as per the data, Employeeno `0122` should appear as `day_in <  2017-06-21` as `2017-06-20` and `day_in > 2017-06-21` as `2017-06-22`.

Comment: @cedric-manacob Please check I have added in an answer. There are 2 approaches to find the result.

Comment: @Cedric Are you trying to employees with day_in  before and after 2017-06-21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use subquery to obtain the result.

```
 SELECT Employeeno FROM [Employee_logs] where day_in<' 2017-06-21' and Employeeno in(
    SELECT Employeeno FROM  [Employee_logs]  where day_in>' 2017-06-21')
```

Comment: @rob-blagg the result can be achieved using above.

Comment: I've tried this result and the result seems correct when I tried it on a sample data. Though I am not able to verify all the result from my million records. I'll accept this answer anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Table Script**

```
  Create table Attendance(Employeeno int ,day_in datetime,day_out datetime)
```

**Insert Record Script**

```
  Insert into Attendance
    Select 0123,'2017-06-20 ','2017-06-21' union
    Select 0123,'2017-06-21 ','2017-06-22' union
    Select 0122,'2017-06-20 ','2017-06-21' union
    Select 0122,'2017-06-22 ','2017-06-23' union
    Select 0121,'2017-06-23 ','2017-06-24'
```

**Approach 1**

```
SELECT Employeeno FROM Attendance where day_in<' 2017-06-21' INTERSECT
SELECT Employeeno FROM Attendance where day_in>' 2017-06-21'
```

For My Above Approach I have used INTERSECT which give common records.
Full usage can bee seen here [https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/17/sql-server-get-common-records-from-two-tables-without-using-join/]

**Approach 2**

```
WITH x AS 
(
    -- Gives the result for Employees with Days_in less 2017-06-21
    SELECT * FROM Attendance where day_in<'2017-06-21'
), 
y AS 
(
      -- Gives the result for Employees with Days_in greater than 2017-06-21
     SELECT * FROM Attendance where day_in>'2017-06-21'
)
SELECT * FROM y join x on y.Employeeno=x.Employeeno 
-- Give the result based on the required query for all employees.
```

Comment: don't use old joins they nasty and i'm not sure that's getting the correct results, although its not that clear in the original post

Comment: Why is this so complicated?  A simple `where` on the original table will satisfy this question...

Comment: @iamdave I would love to solve it using a simple where clause.

Comment: @RohitKumar  Ah I have misunderstood the question, though it can still be a lot simpler, per my answer below.

Comment: @iamdave Thanks for your comments I have updated my answer, Explored INTERSECT usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the earliest and latest `day-in` values using a derived table, you can easily find those that match your criteria:

```
-- Create test data
declare @t table(Employeeno nvarchar(5), day_in date, day_out date);
insert into @t values
 ('0123','2017-06-20','2017-06-21')
,('0123','2017-06-21','2017-06-22')
,('0122','2017-06-20','2017-06-21')
,('0122','2017-06-22','2017-06-23')
,('0121','2017-06-23','2017-06-24');

-- Query
with d as
(
    select Employeeno
            ,min(day_in) as EarliestDayIn
            ,max(day_in) as LatestDayIn
    from @t
    group by Employeeno
)
select *
from d
where EarliestDayIn < '20170621'
    and LatestDayIn > '20170621';
```

Output:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| Employeeno | EarliestDayIn | LatestDayIn |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|       0122 | 2017-06-20    | 2017-06-22  |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I liked the use of table variable instead of permanent table for explanation.